# Bootstrap blocks not acting well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make 2 sections with an image and some text next to it. They may not flow in each other when i change my browser width but i cant fix it..

I want to make it nice underneath each other and when mobile hits first the picture then the text

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/svp3d7fw/

HTML

```
<section class="second-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 image">
            <img src="img/rockwerchter.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 tekst">
            <h2>
            Rock Werchter
            <br>
            30/06 - 03/07
            </h2>
            <p>
                Rock Werchter is officieel én officeus nog steeds het beste festival ter wereld. Op de affiche staan toppers als Sir Paul McCartney, Ellie Goulding, Disclosure en New Order. Overnachten doet u in een luxueuze chalet met een royaal ontbijtbuffet, warmwaterdouches en buitenzwembad.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="second-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 tekst">
            <h2>
            Rock Werchter
            <br>
            30/06 - 03/07
            </h2>
            <p>
                Rock Werchter is officieel én officeus nog steeds het beste festival ter wereld. Op de affiche staan toppers als Sir Paul McCartney, Ellie Goulding, Disclosure en New Order. Overnachten doet u in een luxueuze chalet met een royaal ontbijtbuffet, warmwaterdouches en buitenzwembad.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 image">
            <img src="img/rockwerchter.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
 body {
        padding-top: 50px;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #212121;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .navbar-inverse {
        border-bottom: #ff0021 7px solid;
    }

    .first-block{
        background-color: #e6e6e6;
        padding: 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .first-block h1 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ff0021;
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 15px 0;
    }
    .subline {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }
    .second-block {
        min-height: 463px;
    }
    .col-md-6 {
        height: 250px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    .tekst {
        padding: 25px 45px;
    }
```

Comment: remove the `height` from the `col-md-6` class

Comment: also, since you are using bootstrap, you can use for instance `col-xs-push` on the second text block and `col-xs-pull` on the second image div (on the same div where you set the `col` bootstrap class). that will reorder your divs.

Comment: When i do this he changes the order even on desktop format

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the plunker for the solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6UadTBcpyG9vfxUlLCtp?p=preview

The reason why it reordered the divs on the big screen as well is that (i made a small mistake forgetting this part :) ) you should always put the default position on small screens and use pull and push to reorder on large screens.

here is the code as well for your body:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo%20DM.png" alt="Logo De Morgen" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="Logo van facebook" />
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="Logo van twitter" />
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="first-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>WIN DUO-COMBITICKETS VOOR            <br />
 ROCK WERCHTER & TW CLASSIC</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="subline">Zak dit jaar af naar de heilige weide van Werchter op kosten van De Morgen.            <br />
 Waag uw kans en maak kans op             <strong>duo-combitickets voor Rock Werchter</strong>
            <br />
 en             <strong>TW Classic</strong>
. </p>
          <img src="img/down.png" alt="Next button" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="second-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 image">
          <img src="img/rockwerchter.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 tekst">
          <h2>
                Rock Werchter
                            <br />

                30/06 - 03/07
                </h2>
          <p>
                    Rock Werchter is officieel én officeus nog steeds het beste festival ter wereld. Op de affiche staan toppers als Sir Paul McCartney, Ellie Goulding, Disclosure en New Order. Overnachten doet u in een luxueuze chalet met een royaal ontbijtbuffet, warmwaterdouches en buitenzwembad.
                </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="second-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6 image">
          <img src="img/rockwerchter.png" width="100%" height="auto" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 tekst">
          <h2>
                Rock Werchter
                            <br />

                30/06 - 03/07
                </h2>
          <p>
                    Rock Werchter is officieel én officeus nog steeds het beste festival ter wereld. Op de affiche staan toppers als Sir Paul McCartney, Ellie Goulding, Disclosure en New Order. Overnachten doet u in een luxueuze chalet met een royaal ontbijtbuffet, warmwaterdouches en buitenzwembad.
                </p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')

    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
```